# Errno::ECONNREFUSED in OrdersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

OK, Rails noob asking a question. I'm trying to do Rails for the first time here. I'm reading Agile Web Dev with Rails 4th ed. I'm getting this error on my production box.
This works in development mode under webrick, I get an email sent to my gmail acount and evrything but on my apache box in production mode I get this error...

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED in OrdersController#create
Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Application trace is...

```
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:58:in `create'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:54:in `create'
```

And here is def create in app/controllers/order_controller.rb

```
def create
@order = Order.new(params[:order])
@order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)

respond_to do |format|  #THIS IS LINE 54
  if @order.save
    Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id]) 
    session[:cart_id] = nil 
    Notifier.order_received(@order).deliver     #THIS IS LINE 58
    format.html { redirect_to(store_url, :notice => I18n.t('.thanks')) }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @order, :status => :created, :location => @order }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @order.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

What's wrong with my line 58 and 54? Does this have to do with my action_mailer settings in app/config/environment.rb?

Here is environment.rb

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Depot::Application.initialize!

#uncertain about anything below this line

Depot::Application.configure do 
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address    => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port       => 587,
    :domain     => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :user_name  => "myemail@gmail.com",
    :password   => "<password>",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your app just can't connect to gmail for some reason. Perhaps look into using an alternative service like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com)

Comment: Nothing wrong with line 54, it's just the entry point for that block of code. If you comment out line 58 does the exception go away? Even better try using the [debugger](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/02/09/use-debugger).

Comment: negative commenting out line 58 does not change things.

Comment: Commenting out line 58 should have made the error stop, though of course it's just for confirmation that it's an error connecting to gmail. If you did it in production remember you need to restart your app as the code doesn't automatically reload like it does in development. If you're still having issues, here to help.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue when reading the book, but the following configuration made it work:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  authentication: 'plain',
  user_name: 'myemail@gmail.com',
  password: '<password>'
}
```

Note that I **didn't** include the domain on the `smtp_settings` hash.

One last thing, be sure to **restart your rails application** after you make the changes. That will save you some unnecessary headaches.

Answer (score 2):

Reputation too low to comment, but in @Edgar's answer, also make sure that if you are reading in a YAML config for the smtp settings, you use `symbolize_keys!`:

```
email_settings = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/email.yml"))
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = email_settings[Rails.env].symbolize_keys! unless email_settings[Rails.env].nil?
```

Rails doesn't check for string keys, and goodness, that was a long 3 hours...